# How to change element on hover without changing span inside?

Tags: html, css

I have simple html code and I want to change the h3 tag on :hover but without any impact to a span inside it.

I tried to set H3:hover to text-decoration: underline and H3:hover span to text-decoration: none but it still underline the span as well.

```css
h3 span {
    color: #676767;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

h3 {
    font: 22px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ee0000;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.content:hover h3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content:hover h3 span {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h3>Some H3 title<span class='arrow'>></span></h3>
</div>
```

Why and what is the best way to go around?

Comment: just wrap your inner text that you want styled in a specific span

Comment: Why is there a span inside the h3 in the first place? Use h3:after for that.

Comment: It's not underlining the span. Your span just isn't wrapping anything, so you're not seeing the effect.

Comment: Lain: Still - how to solve it with ::after? The :hover has still impact on the ::after content too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this !!!

```css
h3 span {
    color: #676767;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

h3 {
    font: 22px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ee0000;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.content:hover h3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content:hover h3 span {
    padding-left: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> 
  <h3>Some H3 title<span class='arrow'>></span></h3> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap the inner text in a span and give that a class.

```css
h3 span {
    color: #676767;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

h3 {
    font: 22px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ee0000;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.content:hover h3 span.text {
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content:hover h3 span.arrow {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h3><span class="text">Some H3 title</span><span class='arrow'>></span></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use another `<span>` for text, like:

```
<div class="content">
  <h3><span class="text">Some H3 title</span><span class='arrow'>></span></h3>
</div>
```

And then apply text-decoration on `.text` only.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
h3 .arrow {
  color: #676767;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

h3 .text {
  font: 22px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ee0000;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

h3 .text {
  color: red;
}

.content h3 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content:hover h3 .text {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content:hover h3 .arrow {
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h3><span class="text">Some H3 title</span><span class='arrow'>></span></h3>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer updated**

You can set your span element to `display: inline-block`, and it will not take on the hover effect.

Like this:

```css
h3 span {
    color: #676767;
    padding-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

h3 {
    font: 22px/26px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #ee0000;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.content:hover h3{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content:hover span {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h3>Some H3 title<span class="arrow">></span></h3>
</div>
```

**Thanks to andi for pointing this out in the comment below.**

Comment: the `:not(span)` doesn't actually do anything there.  that just selects an h3 which is not a span (i.e. any h3).  `.content:hover h3:not(span)` is the same as writing `.content:hover h3`

Comment: @andi good point! So it works just by setting the span to inline-block?

Comment: yeah... although I'm not quite sure what the mechanics of that are.

Comment: @andi I'm not sure why that worked either. Thanks for pointing it out, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can style the span specifically to never have an underline:

```
h3 span { 
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Did you try !important?

Comment: that doesn't work either.  did you try it in a real fiddle or snippet?

Comment: Thanks Andi, I see what the problem is now. He's going to have to wrap the words in a span and style that on hover.